In my statement of purpose, should I justify a dropped course that I later made up
I am an international applicant currently applying for a PhD in mathematics in the US, and in my statement of purpose I have highlighted my interest in analysis and topology, but during a summer semester (short semester, two months only) in my undergrad, I had to drop an elective topology course, due to two reasons. During the same semester, I was doing my graduation project, which I did before my graduation semester, to open myself up to the opportunity of doing research, which fortunately worked and I was able to publish a paper. The second reason is the time of the class and life issues.
After my undergrad, I decided to do a master's, where I had a course whose syllabus covered and went over to more advanced topics compared to that dropped course and I was able to get an "A" in it.
Should I try to write about this experience in my SOP or should I leave it out?

The SoP is not the place to make excuses. It should be forward looking, focused on your plans for graduate study and thereafter.
The CV and the grades transcript detail the past.
Additionally, there is no reason to explain or justify dropping a course. It is just part of being a student. If you are asked about it in an interview, explain it then, but I doubt anyone would care.

Indeed, students drop courses all the time for all kinds of reasons. The 'last day to drop a class' date is prominently displayed on every university's calendar I've ever looked at. Many transcripts will not list dropped classes.

Some universities have multiple dates: Last day to drop and receive a full refund.  Last day to drop without a negative mark (W = withdrew) on transcript.  Last day to drop at all (after which the student will receive a grade, probably F).  The presence of the W entry for the course corresponds to when the university administration expects the student to need to explain/offer justification to those receiving the transcript.

@BenVoigt, I'd say "maybe F". Some people drop when doing well for reasons not connected to course progress: health, for example. I don't normally consider W as a negative mark. it doesn't figure into GPA, I expect.

@Buffy: But a student who defacto drops (but is not dropped by the registrar) doesn't earn a grade based on their progress up to that point, it's calculated at the end of the semester.  Just missing a final exam is often enough by itself to tank the grade.  Although in a circumstance where the student had been doing well, they're much more likely to have other options offered, such as "incomplete".

There are situations where it makes sense to address shortcomings of your application in the SOP, e.g. a semester of poor grades related to a physical illness or other temporary obstacle. But I agree that dropping one class will not be considered a big deal by pretty much anyone, and therefore is not worth addressing.
